# PHP how to pass array from view to controller and then to a different view from controller?

Tags: php, arrays, model-view-controller

I have been trying to pass an array that is generated in view to controller.

Say, `$abc=array();` How do I sent this array to controller, then process it and sent this array to another view?

Is it even feasible? Not getting any answer after googling! Please help.

Comment: The view would need to hold the instance of the controller but that would be the opposite of the way it is supposed to be because generally the controller holds an instance of the view. Why do you want to push data up to the controller from the view?

Answer (score 0):

I see no point to generate array from inside the view.

It depends how your framework passes the data between the layers.

For example the controller do pass the data to the View object.

I.e.

```
public function someMethodInController() {
    $this->view->varName['arr_key'] = 'something';
}
```

But talking about view, it might not have a certain controller already instantiated (usually it's against the MVC paradigm)

So I see two major ways:

1. Instantiate a controller (I would not prefer this)

   `$controller = MyController();`
   `$controller->abc = $abc;`
2. Or use sessions. This way to transmit data is universal inbetween your domain, and does not care if you are using a certain pattern, or how do you transmit between layers.

   `$_SESSION['abc'] = $abc;`

Once assigned, you can use it in the same session from each of your files.